# what is it mean "Statement Caches"?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

i read about "Statement Caches" from google and wiki but i unable to understand "Statement Caches"  in database,according to  google the mean of "Statement Caches" :-

> Databases are tuned to do statement caches. They usually include some
>   kind of statement cache. This cache uses the statement itself as a key
>   and the access plan is stored in the cache with the corresponding
>   statement. This allows the database engine to reuse the plans for
>   statements that have been executed previously. For example, if we sent
>   the database a statement such as "select a,b from t where c = 2", then
>   the computed access plan is cached. If we send the same statement
>   later, the database can reuse the previous access plan, thus saving us
>   CPU power. Note however, that the entire statement is the key. For
>   example, if we later sent the statement "select a,b from t where c =
>   3", it would not find an access plan. This is because the "c=3" is
>   different from the cached plan "c=2". So, for example:

```
   For(int I = 0; I < 1000; ++I)
    {
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select a,b from t where c = " + I);
            ResultSet rs = Ps.executeQuery();
            Rs.close();
            Ps.close();
    }
```

> Here the cache won't be used. Each iteration of the loop sends a
>   different SQL statement to the database. A new access plan is computed
>   for each iteration and we're basically throwing CPU cycles away using
>   this approach. However, look at the next snippet: PreparedStatement ps
>   = conn.prepareStatement("select a,b from t where c = ?");

```
For(int I = 0; I < 1000; ++I) {
         ps.setInt(1, I);
         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        Rs.close(); }
```

> ps.close(); Here it will be much more efficient. The statement sent to
>   the database is parameterized using the '?' marker in the sql. This
>   means every iteration is sending the same statement to the database
>   with different parameters for the "c=?" part. This allows the database
>   to reuse the access plans for the statement and makes the program
>   execute more efficiently inside the database. This basically let's
>   your application run faster or makes more CPU available to users of
>   the database.

but i can't understand this code pls somebody give me any idea above this lines.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html explains it well.

Comment: What can't you understand?  Please ask a specific question, and I'll try to answer it.  But if I post a long explanation, you'll possibly just say "I also can't understand that"; and my time will have been wasted.  So try again to read and understand that link, and think about what questions I would need to answer in order to help you understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes time and effort to convert SQL into actual actions.  By noting the result of a given SQL statement the actions can easily be reused if the same SQL statement is issued again giving you a faster response.

The cache is a collection of such time savers.

A prepared statement is a special variant with placeholders designed for this.  The placeholders is then provided for each request without having to redo the "understand this SQL" part every time.